# rollapply mean 5 previuous years

Tags: r, zoo, rollapply

I have a zoo obj like that colled z.

```
> z["2013-12",1]
       Allerona
```

`2013-12-01      0.0
2013-12-02      0.0
2013-12-03      0.0
2013-12-04      0.0
2013-12-05      0.2
2013-12-06      0.0
2013-12-07      0.0
2013-12-08      0.2
2013-12-09      0.0
....`

It stores daily value of rainfall.

I'm able to compute the 5-days accumulation using rollapply usingi:

```
m=rollapply(z, width=3, FUN=sum, by=1, by.column=TRUE, fill=NA, align="right")
```

It looks ok

`> m["2013-12",1]
           Allerona
2013-12-01      0.0
2013-12-02      0.0
2013-12-03      0.0
2013-12-04      0.0
2013-12-05      0.2
2013-12-06      0.2
2013-12-07      0.2
2013-12-08      0.2
2013-12-09      0.2
...`

How can I calculate for each day themean for 5-years before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SMA (x, n=5*365)
```

does not do the trick ?

Comment: I don't know such function. In R base is no present.
Where I can find it?
Thanks

Comment: It's in the TTR package. I assumed  if you were using zoo, you were probably also using XTS and TTR. Anyway you can install xts and get loads of Time Series functions

Comment: I tried.
I obtain:
`> SMA(m,n = 5*365)

Error in runSum(x, n) : not enough non-NA values `

Comment: There seems to  be lots of missing data for earlier periods. You will need some strategy to fill them. You can check ?na.fill  . Anyway, it seems Moving Averages are what you are looking for. You can calculate SMAs for shorter periods and see if they work the way you wanted. Then worry about the missing data.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted my problem.
The solution was to use a list into the width parameter of rollapply.
here below the code:

`mean5year=rollapply(as.zoo(m), list(-365*5:1), function(x) {mean(x,na.rm = TRUE)},fill=NA)`

where

`list(-365*5:1)`

takes the same day but in the previous 5-years. I should also use a mean with na.rm =TRUE to compute mean also if NA are in the sequence